# PHP Generating XML, getting Extra content at the end of the document

Tags: php, xml

just trying to generate a simple XML document using PHP, I found an example which seems to be working, how ever im getting this error:

> This page contains the following errors:
>
> error on line 5 at column 1: Extra content at the end of the document
>   Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.

Here is my PHP code:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement("<xml/>");
$form_data = array(
    "name" => $_POST['name'],
    "email" => $_POST['email'],
    "message" => $_POST['message'],
    "reg" => $_POST['reg'],
    "image" => $image_location
);

$xml->addChild('uploaded',serialize($_POST));
$xml->addChild('imageerror',"imageerror");

header('Content-type: text/xml');
print($xml->asXML());
```

This is what I get if I view my page source:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xml><uploaded>a:0:{}</uploaded><imageerror>imageerror</imageerror></xml>

<!-- Hosting24 Analytics Code -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://stats.hosting24.com/count.php"></script>
<!-- End Of Analytics Code -->
```

So it does seem to generate the XML properly, but the web hosting is adding some crap, is that is what would be causing the error, if so is the only way to stop that to change webhost?

Comment: Try adding `die()` after you print the result.

Comment: Yes, thanks, didn't think of that. Add it as an answer please. Stupid web host messing up my code!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 3 approaches for doing this:

1) There is always in link in their cPanels that disables the analytics code in your code. Most of time the link of file is `Your_web_host_url/analytics.php` . But always consider that by doing this you deny their policy and they will eventually delete your account and it causes losing your data.

2) You can use a `exit` command at the end of your php script.

3) Create a `.htaccess` in your `public_html` folder and add the following
   code to it:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(php)$">
php_value auto_append_file none
</FilesMatch>
```

replace `.php` with any type of file that you don't want analytics in it.

Answer (score 2):

Shame on the hosting provider here. For others experiencing the same problem, `die()` will stop the execution and thus will not add the analytics code from hosting24.

Comment: Thanks, but accepted the other answer as I think it gives a more wide range of answers.

Answer (score 2):

It much depends on *how* the analytics code gets added. You can try disabling the `php_auto_append` directive in .htaccess, or inspect your php.ini values through whatever control panel your hosting is offering. If you normally *use* the analytics code *and* the above otherwise works, put your XML/JSON files into a separate folder, ensure that the Apache AllowOverride directive for the virtualHost contains `FileInfo` (or it is set to `All`) and place your XML/JSON-generating files in that folder together with a `.htaccess`

```
php_value   "auto_append_file"      None
```

These are, so to speak, the "official/elegant" ways of doing this. Opening a ticket with your hoster is the recommended way to go should this not be enough.

**Given that sending analytics code will break all sort of JSON/XML services**, it is a fair bet that there **is** an easy way of disabling it. It may involve placing the file in a specific folder (i.e., the above workaround is actually already in place), or giving it a specific name server side, or something else - but there *should* be a way.

That said, **if** nothing else works, you can try to get the client browser to ignore the extra content:

```
$actualContent = $xml->asXML();
Header('Content-Type: text/xml');
Header('Content-Length: ' . strlen($actualContent));
Header('Connection: close');
die($actualContent);
```

If the above headers arrive intact to the client (the hoster could mess with them too...), the connection will drop and only the first "valuable" bytes will get considered. **THIS IS A HACK**, because it relies on undocumented/untested behaviour.

Another similar hack involves sending a multipart header with the first part ending after your `$actualContent` is sent, followed by a unhandled MIME-type. Any client expecting XML will extract the first section and ignore the rest. This too is not clean behaviour since the transmission will lack the ending block.

For the same reason, ending the XML in a comment `<!--` *might* work with some browsers.